# Jenkins udeploy plugin log4j issues

Tags: jenkins, log4j

Has anyone successfully updated the log4j jar file for jenkins to get the udeploy plugin working by following the instructions provided on their site http://wiki.urbancode.com/uDeploy/Repositories, seen below?

**Note:** Jenkins often uses an older log4j file then our plugin needs. You may need to replace it. See below for instructions:
1. Unpackage the jenkins.war
2. Open /web-inf/lib in the unpacked .war's directory to determine the name of Jenkin's log4j.jar
3. Navigate to your uDeploy server's %serverLocation%/lib directory and copy our log4j.jar to Jenkin's /web-inf/lib/ directory, overwriting the existing log4j with uDeploy's (rename it to match Jenkin's)

On standalone instances of Jenkins (not the Tomcat app), Jenkins keeps a hash of all of it's files and will throw an error when starting Jenkins due to a mismatched hash after modifying the log4j file. The only solution is to remove the values in the file that tracks the hashes."

I unpackaged the war file, deleted the log4j jar (1.2.9) found under WEB-INF/lib/, added the newest log4j jar (1.2.17), renamed it to 1.2.9, then removed the SHA1-Digest: line (the hash) for log4j 1.2.9 found in the manifest under META-INF/ all which seems to agree with the above instructions. Deploying the war (service jenkins start) results in the following error, complaining that the SHA1 signature isn't there in the manifest:

```
Starting Jenkins Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(SignatureFileVerifier.java:457)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:250)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:193)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:262)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:216)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:341)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:406)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:752)
        at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:476)
                                                           [FAILED]
```

What am I missing? I thought I followed the directions correctly, and evidently enough people have had this problem given that uDeploy added a special note to their wiki page about it. Any help/suggestions/ideas would be highly appreciated.

Jenkins is version 1.525.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still interested in solution, I didn't remove digests. Just deleted log4j-1.2.9.jar and added log4j-1.2.17.jar (without renaming), that's all I did. An it worked brilliantly. Jenkins version 1.542.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you rename it to 1.2.9? It will probably work as named as 1.2.17. It's a signed jar, and renaming it may be why it broke.

If jenkins is running on tomcat on linux, you are probably faster just logging into the box to the webapps directory and altering the expanding war there rather than repacking the jenkins war.

Comment: I renamed it to 1.2.9 bc that's what the official directions on urbancode were. Leaving it named as is and deleting the 1.2.9 entry from the manifest produced the following error - if you have insight into why jenkins still looks for 1.2.9 after it was deleted (and expanded war cache cleared), it would be greatly appreciated: Starting Jenkins Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for signature file entry WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(SignatureFileVerifier.java:399)
        at sun.security.ut..

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to change the log4j version and solve the stated uDeploy problem :-

1. Stop Jenkins
2. Go to the installation directory of Jenkins
3. Navigate to .jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib [On a windows system]
4. Delete log4j-1.2.9.jar and add log4j-1.2.17.jar (without renaming)
5. Restart Jenkins

It is not necessary to follow all the steps given as a solution by IBM :-
https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugin/jenkins-ibmucd/

Answer (score 0):

At this point, just use the new version of the Jenkins plugin. The incompatibility was removed.